# Polymer app not passing route parameters to component.

Tags: routes, polymer, polymer-1.0, polymer-starter-kit

I am trying to access the url parameters in a polymer application using pagejs and I am unable to find out why the value remains unaccessible inside the components.

Here is what I had done on the routing.html file

```
page('/crews/edit/:crewId', function(data) {
        app.params = data.params;      
        app.route = 'crew-edit';
        setFocus(app.route);
    });
```

which I then tried to pass into the page component

```
<section data-route="crew-edit" tabindex="-1">
        <bw-crew-edit crewId="{{ app.params.crewId }}"></bw-crew-edit>
</section>
```

and then finally into the component itself

```
<dom-module is="bw-crew-edit">
  <template>
      {{crewId}}    
  </template>
  <script>
    (function() {
        "use strict";

        Polymer({
            is: 'bw-crew-edit',
            properties: {              
              crewId: {
                type: String,
                notify: true,
                observers: '_crewIdChanged'
              }
            },
            _crewIdChanged: function() {
              console.log(this.crewId);
            },

        });

    })();
  </script>
</dom-module>
```

I am sure that I have followed the order of things and am unable to figure out why the component isn't receiving the data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As indicated in Polymer [docs](https://www.polymer-project.org/1.0/docs/devguide/properties#property-name-mapping):

> ### Property name to attribute name mapping
>
> ...
>
> When mapping attribute names to property names:
>
> - Attribute names are converted to lowercase property names. For example, the attribute `firstName` maps to `firstname`.
> - Attribute names with dashes are converted to camelCase property names by capitalizing the character following each dash, then removing the dashes. For example, the attribute `first-name` maps to `firstName`.

In your case, you would use the `crew-id` attribute to set the `crewId` property of your element:

```
<bw-crew-edit crew-id="foo">
```

```html
<head>
  <base href="https://polygit.org/polymer+1.4.0/components/">
  <script src="webcomponentsjs/webcomponents-lite.min.js"></script>
  <link rel="import" href="polymer/polymer.html">
</head>
<body>
  <bw-crew-edit crew-id="foo"></bw-crew-edit>

  <dom-module id="bw-crew-edit">
    <template>
      <span>crewId: {{crewId}}</span>
    </template>
    <script>
      HTMLImports.whenReady(function() {
        Polymer({
          is: 'bw-crew-edit',
          properties : {
            crewId: String
          },
          ready: function() {
            console.log('crewId', this.crewId);
          }
        });
      });
    </script>
  </dom-module>
</body>
```

<sup>[codepen](http://codepen.io/tony19/pen/BzyeYo?editors=1000)</sup>